# Multiple Axios Requests Into Vue

Tags: arrays, json, vue.js, axios, concatenation

I have two different json endpoints I'm using in a Vue JS app. Currently I'm display's posts in a home view. Then using Vue router I'm creating a details view with more specific post info. I would like to for comments to show up from endpoint `/comments` to appear in the details view if the comment id matches the post id.

posts `/posts`

comments `/comments`

```
import axios from 'axios'

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/'
})
const basePost = '/posts'
const baseComments = '/comments'

export default {
  fetchPosts () {
    return instance
      .get(basePost)
      .then(response => response.data)
  }
}
```

How would I concatenate both arrays into one and then set that to retrieve posts and comments in a view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `axios` get returns `promise`, so u can call both parallel and get the promises to resolve using Promise.all.

**Example 1:** Using `Promise.all`

```js
//const axios = require("axios");
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/",
});
const basePost = "/posts";
const baseComments = "/comments";
const service = {
  fetchPosts() {
    const promises = [instance.get(basePost), instance.get(baseComments)];
    return Promise.all(promises).then(([posts, comments]) => [
      posts.data,
      comments.data,
    ]);
  },
};
service.fetchPosts().then(console.log);
// export default service;
```

```css
.as-console-row {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.js"></script>
```

**Note:** If you want in `series` way meaning post first then comment u can use `async-await`.

**Example 2:** Using `async-await`

```js
//const axios = require("axios");
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/",
});
const basePost = "/posts";
const baseComments = "/comments";
const service = {
  async fetchPosts() {
    const posts = await instance.get(basePost).then((x) => x.data);
    const comments = await instance.get(baseComments).then((x) => x.data);
    //console.log(posts, comments);
    return [posts, comments];
  },
};
// export default service;

service.fetchPosts().then(console.log);
```

```css
.as-console-row {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.js"></script>
```

Comment: For clarity, you should add a comment between the two examples, or better: create one snippet each. Currently, this solution seems bigger than it really is.